# jQuery: Add Parent's ID to Child's rel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the paren't ID to its child's rel. I'd like this

```
<div id="gallery-1>
 <a href="">
 <a href="">
</div>
<div id="gallery-2">
 <a href="">
 <a href="">
</div>
```

to look like this:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery">
 <a href="" rel="gallery-1">
 <a href="" rel="gallery-1">
</div>
<div id="gallery-2" "class="gallery">
 <a href="" rel="gallery-2">
 <a href="" rel="gallery-2">
</div>
```

My code:

```
$('.gallery a').attr('rel', $(this).parent('.gallery').attr('id'));
```

Comment: your divs have ids not classes, your jquery is using class (the period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the code into a callback. Otherwise, it's called in the original function, not for each element in the collection.

```
$(".gallery > a").attr("rel", function() {
    return $(this).parent().attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("div").each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var id = $this.attr("id");
     $this.children().attr("rel", id);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tr5wem0/

Comment: try with this selector `$("div[id^='gallery'] > a")`